# ANDROID:How to access fragment layout objects?

Tags: android

I have an app that uses fragments.I'm using backward compability package with Android 2.2. I can inflate xml just fine, but problem starts when I try to access objects on the inflated layout. LogCat throws "Error inflating class fragment". What I'm doing wrong ? Here is my code :

```
View view001 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_right_view,container,false);
TextView text001= (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
text001.setText("Sample text");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
View view001 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_right_view,container,false);
TextView text001= (TextView)view001.findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
text001.setText("Sample text");
```